# Partially lift with liftIO

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do something that's probably impossible.  I have a type that is an instance of `MonadIO`.  If you `liftIO` an `IO` action in a context where this type is the base monad of some transformer stack, it will work fine.  So, what I'd like to be able to do is take a value that's already been lifted part-way (to my type) and lift it "the rest of the way" in one step.

I can do this in two ways.  One is that my type can actually be trivially re-embedded into normal IO, so I can do this:

```
liftMore :: (MonadIO m) => MyType a -> m a
liftMore x = liftIO $ embedMyTypeInIO x
```

And this works.  However, this also provides a way to fully escape from my type if used in context where just `IO` is the base monad, which is undesirable.

I can also do this by building a new typeclass like `MonadIO` that uses my type as a base, but then it needs to be instantiated for everything, which is very undesirable.  I tried using a newtype wrapper to make every monad transformer an instance of such a class, but couldn't quite get it.

Any ideas on strategies I could try to accomplish this?  (I'm willing to play with language extensions, but of course a solution that is Haskell98 is much preferrable).

Comment: Most monad transformers already provide an instance of the form: `instance (MonadIO m) => MonadIO (SomeTransformer m) where ...`.  Would that be sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `MonadBase` instead of `MonadIO`? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-base

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez no, because I want to lift *from* my type *to* anything in `MonadIO`.  `liftIO` only lets my lift from `IO` itself.

Comment: @NathanHowell despite using several ickier extensions, `MonadBase` seems like the sort of thing I could provide an instance of to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: @NathanHowell you should provide your comment as an answer, since it resolves the question.

Comment: _I can also do this by building a new typeclass like MonadIO that uses my type as a base, but then it needs to be instantiated for everything_  - Actually, if you are willing to use UndecidableInstances and OverlappingInstances, you can just define an instance for your base monad and one for MonadTrans.